# Negation of "For all x ∈ R, if ⌊5x⌋ = 5⌊x⌋, then x ∈ Z"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Negation of "For all x ∈ R, if ⌊5x⌋ = 5⌊x⌋, then x ∈ Z"

Is there only one correct negation?

I know "There exists x ∈ R, so that ⌊5x⌋ = 5⌊x⌋, but x ∉ Z" is correct.

But what about: "For some x ∈ R, ⌊5x⌋ = 5⌊x⌋ and x ∉ Z" ?

Comment: There is no difference in what you wrote.  The only differences are that you used slightly different words that serve the same grammatical purpose.

Comment: What difference do you make between the two sentences? *l’m not a native English and may have missed nuances !*

Comment: I think they are the same, but was told by a teacher that the second one is an incorrect negation. @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: "there exists" and "for some" mean the same thing.  At least to a mathematician they do.

Comment: I think your teacher is wrong.  Sadly that happens.  Sadly it seems to happen a lot.

Comment: "There exists an $x$ where stuff happens" means for that $x$ stuff happens and so for some $x$ (namely *THAT* $x$) stuff happens.  SO "there exist $x$" $\implies$ "For some $x$". And if "For some $x$ stuff happes" then for those $x$es, the exist.  And at least one of them exists.  So "For some $x$" $\implies$ "there exists $x$".... They both mean the exact same thing.

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote is equivalent. Here is another equivalency, but a shorter one:
$$
\exists x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Z} \text{ such that }
\lfloor 5x \rfloor = 5\lfloor x\rfloor
$$

Answer (score 2):

Formally negation for $$(\forall x \in R)(⌊5x⌋ = 5⌊x⌋ \Rightarrow x \in Z)$$ is $$(\exists x \in R)(⌊5x⌋ = 5⌊x⌋ \land x \notin Z )$$
You can use several variants how to say it, but while you mean what is written, then they are same.